# Is it or not a continuous embedding?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Please I have this two spaces $$C_{\theta}=\{u\in C(\overline{\Omega}), \sup (|x|^{\theta} |u(x)|)<\infty\}$$ with the norm $\displaystyle||u||_{\theta}=\sup_{\Omega}(|x|^{\theta} |u(x)|)$

and $$L_{\frac{N}{p}}^{p^*}=\{u ~~\text{measurable};~~\int_{\Omega} (|x|^{\frac{N}{p}} |u(x)|)^{p^*} dx<\infty\}$$ with the norm $||u||_{L^{p^*}_{\frac{N}{p}}}^{p^*}=\int_{\Omega} (|x|^{\frac{N}{p}}|u(x)|)^{p^*}dx$

Where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is bounded with $0\in \Omega$ and $\theta>\frac{N}{p},$ $p^*=\frac{pN}{N-p}$ and $N>p.$

My question is can i prove that there is continuous injection between $C_{\theta}$ and $L^{p^*}_{\frac{N}{p}}$ i.e can we prove that $$\forall C>0, ||u||_{L^{p^*}_{\frac{N}{p}}}\leq C ||u||_{\theta}$$ if not what is the counter example ?

Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that
$$\tag{*}   p^*\left(\theta -\frac Np\right) \gt N.$$
This condition appears after having considered the convergence of the integral $I:=\int_\Omega(|x|^{N/p} |x|^{-\theta})^{p^*} \mathrm dx$. Indeed, since we integrate a radial function, $I$ converges if and only if $\int_0^1 (r^{N /p}r^{-\theta})^{p^*}r^{N-1}\mathrm dr       $ converges, which converges if and only if $p^*(N/p-\theta)+N\gt 0$.

Then one can show that $\lVert u\rVert_{L_{\frac{N}{p}}^{p^*}}\leqslant C(\theta,N,p)\lVert u\rVert_\theta$ exploiting the inequality $|u(x)|\leqslant \lVert u\rVert_\theta|x|^{-\theta}    $ for any $x\in\Omega$.

If (*) is not satisfied, then consider the sequence of function $u_n(x)=a_n(x)|x|^{-\theta}$, where $a_n(x)=b_n(|x|)$ and $b_n$ is continuous, $b_n(t)=1$ if $|t|\in(2/n,\infty)$ and $b_n(t)=0$ if $|t|\lt1/n$.

Comment: i don't understand we have the continuous embedding ?

Comment: Not always, I think; only when the displayed inequality  is satisfied.

Comment: but we have problem with 0 , when we consider $|x|^{-\theta}$ no ?

Comment: why $|x|^{-\theta}$ must be in $L^{p^*}_{\frac{N}{p}}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou You are right, there is a technical issue here. I have edited.

Comment: but i just don't understand how you find the condition  $p^*\left(\theta -\frac Np\right) -N\gt 1.$ thank you

Comment: if i suppose that $||u||_{L^{p^*}_{\frac{N}{p}}}\leq C ||u||_{\theta}$ i.e $\left(\int_{\Omega} (|x|^{\frac{N}{p}} |u(x)|)^{p^*}) dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p^*}}\leq C (\sup_{\Omega} (|x|^{\theta}|u(x)|)$ how can i find your condition, please

Comment: i say as you started $|u(x)|\leq ||u||_{\theta} |x|^{-\theta}$ then $\int_{\Omega}(|x|^{\frac{N}{p}} |u(x)|)^{p^*}dx\leq ||u||_{\theta}^{p^*} \int_{\Omega} |x|^{(-\theta+\frac{N}{p})p^*} dx$ then the condition is $-\theta+\frac{N}{p}>0$ which is impossible because $\theta >\frac{N}{p}$

Comment: I've edited in order to make (*) less mysterious.

Comment: to have that $\int_\Omega(|x|^{N/p} |x|^{-\theta})^{p^*} \mathrm dx$ converge we just need to have that $\frac{N}{p}-\theta >0$ no ?

Comment: there is a problem with your condition it must be $p^*\left(\theta -\frac Np\right) -N\gt 0$ and i not sure about your example

Comment: @Vrouvrou You are right, and I have edited again. The example shows that the wanted constant $C$ cannot exists.

Comment: but in the example when we are not near 0 the integral converge ! so C exist, can you please give me more calculation details about this example ? Thank you

Comment: see this question is your example can be used here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284540/a-counter-example