# A counter example

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I have this two spaces $$C_{\theta}=\{u\in C(\overline{\Omega}), \sup (|x|^{\theta} |u(x)|)<\infty\}$$ with the norm $\displaystyle\|u
\|_{\theta}=\sup_{\Omega}(|x|^{\theta} |u(x)|)$

and $$L_{1}^{p^*}=\{u ~~\text{measurable};~~\int_{\Omega} (|x|\cdot|u(x)|)^{p^*} dx<\infty\}$$ with the norm $\|u\|_{L^{p^*}_{1}}^{p^*}=\int_{\Omega} (|x|\cdot|u(x)|)^{p^*}dx$

Where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is bounded with $0\in \Omega$ and $\theta>\frac{N}{p}>1,$ $p^*=\frac{pN}{N-p}$ and $N>p.$

I need a counter example to say that  $C_{\theta}$ is not continuously embeded in $L^{p^*}_{1}$, so i'm searching a function which is in $C_{\theta}$ but not in $L^{p^*}_1$

**Or a sequence $u_n$ which converge to $u$ un $C_{\theta}$ but not in $L^{p^*}_{1}$**

Please help me thank you

Comment: What wuld a counter-example look like here? Sounds like you just need a proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  if you have a direct prove i prefer , give me any idea

Comment: I don't have any proof. But "There does not exist an X" isn't usually be proven with a counterexample.

Comment: but how i must do ? i need to be sure that there is no continuous embedding @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you tel me if the example given in the answer of this question can the counter example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267849/is-it-or-not-a-continuous-embedding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a canonical test function, $u(x)=|x|^\alpha$ and see if some value of $\alpha$ works. Suppose $\Omega=B(0,1)$. Then
$$
\sup_{x\in\Omega}|x|^\theta|u(x)|=1\tag{1}
$$
as long as $\alpha+\theta\ge0$.
$$
\int_\Omega|xu(x)|^{p^*}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\omega_{N-1}\int_0^1r^{(1+\alpha)p^*}r^{N-1}\,\mathrm{d}r\tag{2}
$$
which is finite when $0\lt(1+\alpha)p^*+N=N\left[\frac{(1+\alpha)p}{N-p}+1\right]$. This is equivalent to
$$
\frac{(1+\alpha)p}{N-p}\gt-1\iff\alpha\gt-\frac Np\tag{3}
$$
For a counterexample, we would need
$$
-\theta\le\alpha\le-\frac Np\tag{4}
$$
Since $\frac Np\lt\theta$ by hypothesis, we can find an $\alpha$ strictly between $-\theta$ and $-\frac Np$. Thus, for $\alpha$ satisfying $(4)$, $u=|x|^\alpha$ and $\Omega=B(0,1)$ satisfy $(1)$, yet fail to have $(2)$ converge.

---

Since the question also wants $u\in C(\overline{\Omega})$, $C_\theta$ is not closed. We have to limit our functions to be in $C(\overline{\Omega})$. So, define
$$
u_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
|x|^\alpha&\text{if }|x|\ge\frac1n\\
\frac1{n^\alpha}&\text{if }|x|\lt\frac1n
\end{array}\right.
$$
So each $u_n$ is in $C(\overline{\Omega})$ and satisfies $(1)$. However, $u_n\to u$ monotonically as $n\to\infty$; thus, by [Monotone Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem), we have that $\|u_n\|_{\large L_{p^\ast}^1}\to\infty$.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you <3 <3 <3

Comment: i can suppose that $diam(\Omega)=\rho$ and then say that $\sup_{x\in\Omega}|x|^\theta|u(x)|=\rho$

Comment: There is one thing, when $\alpha <0$ $u\not in C$ which is a condition on $C_{\theta}$ so there is a problem

Comment: As I mentioned in $(1)$, as long as $\alpha+\theta\ge0$, we have that $u\in C_\theta$. So there is no problem as long as $\alpha\ge-\theta$, which is part of $(4)$.

Comment: but when $\alpha$ is negative , $|x|^{\alpha}\notin C$

Comment: Yes it is, as long as $\alpha+\theta\ge0$. Look at the definition of $C_\theta$.

Comment: but the definition of $C_{\theta}$ says that u must be in C after that $\sup (|x|^{\theta} u(x)|<\infty$

Comment: What satisfy $\varepsilon^{\alpha}$ and why (2 ) is not finite please

Comment: Since each $u_n$ is now continuous, we must have that $(2)$ is finite, but each one is monotonically increasing to $|x|^\alpha$, so the norm in $(2)$ grows without bound, yet the $C_\theta$ norm in $(1)$ stays at $1$.

Comment: in the sequence $u_n(x) =|x|^{\alpha}$ when $|x|\geq \frac1n$ and $n^{-\alpha},$ for $|x|<\frac1n$ so when $n$ tends to $\infty$ we have $|x|^{\alpha}$ for $|x|\geq 0$ and $\infty, $for $|x|<0$ we know that |x| is positive so the secand case is refused and then the limite of $ u_n$ is $|x|^{\alpha}$
i don't understand how we use the monotonicity convergence in order to find the limit of u_n ?

Comment: We don't use the monotonicity of the sequence $u_n$ to show that the limit of $u_n$ is $u$. That is obvious by the definition of $u_n$. We use the monotonicity of the sequence $u_n$ to guarantee that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|u_n\|_{L_{p^\ast}^1}=\infty$. Since $\|u_{n+1}\|_{L_{p^\ast}^1}\ge\|u_n\|_{L_{p^\ast}^1}$, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|u_n\|_{L_{p^\ast}^1}\lt\infty$, then Monotone Convergence guarantees that $\|u\|_{L_{p^\ast}^1}\lt\infty$.

Comment: where i can find this version of monotone convergence ? please

Comment: I have added a link to my answer.

Comment: thank you i think that i understand

Comment: the problem here is that the limite of $(u_n)$ is not in $C_{\theta}$ because $u_n$ tends to $|x|^{\alpha}$ and $|x|^{\alpha}$ is not in $C$

Comment: Why do we care about the limit of $u_n$? The point is that $(1)$ is true for each $u_n$, but $\|u_n\|_{\large L_{p^\ast}^1}\to\infty$.

Comment: my prof told me that the limit must be in $C_{\theta}$, have you an idea about this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298594/example-of-bounded-sequence-in-a-space-but-not-convergent-in-an-other-space

Comment: Since $C\subset L_1^{p^\ast}(\Omega)$ and the restriction that $C_\theta\subset C$, you cannot find a function in $C_\theta$ that is not in $L_1^{p^\ast}(\Omega)$. The idea is to show that the inclusion is not continuous. If it were continuous, there would be a constant, $K$, so that for all $f\in C_\theta$, $$\|f\|_{L_1^{p^\ast}(\Omega)}\le K\|f\|_{C_\theta}$$ The sequence in the answer shows that there is no such constant.

Comment: Why $C\subset L^{p^*}_1$ ?

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact set is bounded, and $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact by Heine-Borel. Since the product of continuous functions is continuous, $xu(x)$ is continuous. Therefore,
$$
\left(\int_{\overline{\Omega}}|xu(x)|^{p^\ast}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p^\ast}\le\sup_{x\in\Omega}|xu(x)|\,\mu\big(\overline{\Omega}\big)^{1/p^\ast}
$$

Comment: please is the sequence $u_n$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}_0$?

Comment: The sequence is **not** bounded. Each $u_n$ **is**.

Comment: how it is bounded but enach u_n is bounded ?

Comment: $u_n\le\frac1{n^\alpha}$ means $u_n$ is bounded. $\|u_n\|_{L_1^{p^\ast}}\to\infty$ when $(4)$ is satisfied.

Comment: is it bounded in $W^{1,p}_0$ ? is it good to say that this sequence is bounded in W^{1,p}_0 and all it's subsequence do not converge in $L^{p^*}_1$?

Comment: Where does $W_0^{1,p}$ enter into the question? The question only mentions $C_\theta$ and $L_1^{p^\ast}$.

Comment: I know but in reality i need that $W^{1,p}_0$ do not compactly embeded in $L^{p^*}_1$ As $W^{1,p}$ in compactly embeded in $C_{\theta}$ i thinked that it will be sufficient to prove that $C_{\theta}$ is not continuously embeded in $L^{p^*}_1$

Comment: If $W_0^{1,p}$ embeds continuously in $C_\theta$ and $C_\theta$ embeds continuously in $L_1^{p^\ast}$ implies that $W_0^{1,p}$ embeds continuously in $L_1^{p^\ast}$, we have $P\land Q\implies R$. However, it does not follow that $P\land\lnot Q\implies\lnot R$.

Comment: I know i do a mistake, do you know where i can found the proof of $W^{1,p}$ do not compactly embed in $L^{p^*}$ ? i want to give an answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207675/condition-to-obtain-a-not-compact-embedding

Comment: Have you tried the method used here? That is, checking the conditions for the $u_n$ I give here?

Comment: i have problem to prove the boudedness on $W^{1,p}_0$